# shared mem betwwen kernel/user space and select

Tags: linux, select, shared-memory, freebsd

I have some specific hardware which run on FreeBSD and Linux.

I have to do an user space application which will work with the driver using shared memory between kernel/user space application.
My application does busy poll on the shared mem from user space.
Is there any idea how I can use a mechanism such select to sleep and to get notify on shared memory change (buy the driver) ?

I dont want to implement some communication like netlink, because the idea with select is to sleep, to wake up if something happens, and to keep awake and keep processing data without handing more IPC with the kernel.
And then, when it will be done, the application can call again select and wait again.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the kqueue(2) interface on FreeBSD.
On Linux there is inotify/epoll.